# How to create annotation in isolated business logic module to be interpreted by spring in application module

Tags: java, spring, module, annotations, clean-architecture

I need to create annotation to tell Spring that given class should be a bean of given scope. In general it's quite easy, I just create annotation annotated with `@Scope` and `@Component` and it simply works.

But...

I want to keep my code isolated as a business logic module and don't want it to be dependent on external library like *spring-context*.

So, the goal is to create some annotation and at the application module tell Spring to interpret it as something annotated with `@Scope` and `@Component`.

Is it even possible?

EDIT: I should add, the scope I need to use is custom scope.